# How to kill a process dependent on its switch

Tags: windows, cmd

I would like to kill a process, although only kill a process with a specific switch, e.g.

> `taskkill "cmd.exe" /s /k pushd`

Can you do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to some extent but will be unreliable. For one the command line is part of the process' memory, so it's free to modify it. In addition to that what about `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` or `C:\WINNT\System32\cmd.exe` on a Windows 2000. You'd have to implement some heuristics to catch as many variants as possible.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to write a program like taskkill as you've described?  Or are you looking for something that already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for listing all running processes using the [Windows Process Status API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). After that, try to get the process's command line, like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) does (it seems that this can be done through an [undocumented API](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/)). Next, just kill the process that matches your criteria using the same PSAPI above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. The `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` struct has a member `PebBaseAddress` witch is a pointer to the [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. From there you can check the `ProcessParameters` member which is a pointer to a [`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. Finally you can check its `CommandLine` member.